# Chai: assert array includes all items

Tags: javascript, chai

Is it possible to assert that an array includes multiple specific items using chai?

For example, I would expect this to work:

```
['foo', 'bar'].should.include(['foo', 'bar'])
```

Instead chai throws: "expected [ 'foo', 'bar' ] to include [ 'foo', 'bar' ]"

I also tried this but it only asserts that the first item is present:

```
['foo', 'bar'].should.include('foo', 'bar') // variable args instead of array
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 40):

You can use [members](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#members) to expect array members.

Ex:

```
expect(['foo', 'bar']).to.include.members(['foo', 'bar'])
```

Comment: Is the way to assert that:
 expect(['foo', 'bar'])"contains at least one of"(['foo', 'bar'])
so the array contains one or more elements from other array
Becouse .to.include.members is true if one array is exact the same as the other. 
I need to assert that array contains at least one value from other array